# Pentaquark found in LHC

Tags: pentaquarks

Good Afternoon,

So one of the 2 pentaquarks possibly found in the LHC was U,U,D,C,-C
My question is that wouldn't the  C/-C annihilate each other almost immediately, leaving the U,U,D?

How long could such a particle last?

Comment: The strong force gets weaker at short distances, so, unlike for the electromagnetic force, there is no continually increasing attraction leading to annihilation. You basically just have to wait for them to happen to collide, which takes some time (not a lot of time, as the confining space is tiny, but far more time than instantaneously).

Comment: @probably_someone I know that the QCD is asymptotically free, but then what do [these plots of the static quark potential mean](http://inspirehep.net/record/886793/plots)? For short distances the potential goes as $1/r$.

Comment: I admit the explanation above was extremely hand-wavey and not entirely accurate. That said, quarks in hadrons are subject to highly non-perturbative interactions, so we shouldn't expect a perturbative theory to explain something like the OP's question very well.

Comment: Rick, you might as well ask the same question about the stability of charmonium mesons: why don't they decay "almost immediately"?  Actually they are longer-lived than your pentaquarks.

Comment: *almost immediately* is relative.  The lifetime of typical mesons which contain quark-anti-quark pairs are very short ($\sim 10^{-24}$ sec) but that does not mean the particle doesn't exist at all.  It just has to exist long enough to decay into something else.  So $uudc\bar{c}$ would be expected to be very unstable.